# how to use intent in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onclick

I'm developing an application that calculates the tips. A user enters an amount and clicks on a button that opens another activity showing the value of the tip he should pay. I have an error in my code, but I don't know how to fix it. Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:hint="Bill amount in L.L"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10%"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:onClick="tenp"/>
```

activity_result.xml:

```
<TextView android:text="@string/result" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public void tenp(View view1) {

        Intent myintent= new Intent(this, Result.class);
        EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        String s = e.getText().toString();
        startActivity(myintent);

    }
```

Result.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);


          Intent i = getIntent();
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(i.getText().toString());

            double res = (amount / 100.0f) * 15;

            String m = amount.getStringExtra("L.L");

           TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);

            t.setText(m);




        }
```

and this is the error:

```
Error:(23, 49) error: cannot find symbol method getText()
Error:(27, 30) error: double cannot be dereferenced
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you are not passing any value with your intent. You have to put the String in the intent bundle. You can do it with `putExtra()` method:

```
public void tenp(View view1) {
    Intent myintent= new Intent(this, Result.class);
    EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    String s = e.getText().toString();
    myintent.putExtra("MyStringValue", s);
    startActivity(myintent);
}
```

and then you have to get this value in `Result.java` class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String myString = extras.getString("MyStringValue");        
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(myString);

    double res = (amount / 100.0f) * 15;

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    t.setText(res);
}
```

Honestly i don't know what you want to set in the textview so i put "res" but my example can help you to receive your string from the first activity.

Comment: I'm reading a double from the EditText. Your code is giving this error:Error:(22, 33) error: cannot find symbol method getStringExtra(String)

Comment: no suitable method found for setText(double)
method TextView.setText(int,BufferType) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method TextView.setText(int) is not applicable
(actual argument double cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
method TextView.setText(char[],int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method TextView.

Comment: setText(CharSequence,BufferType) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable
(actual argument double cannot be converted to CharSequence by method invocation conversion)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getText()` method for an `Intent`. To use an `Intent`, use the following code in your MainActivity:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
intent.putExtra("amount", editText.getText().toString());
```

In your Result class, use the following code to retrieve the `Intent` extra:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

String amount = intent.getStringExtra("amount");
```

You may want to check out [the documentation regarding Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with using string and double in the wrong places. Here is how I fixed this:

Result.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String myString = i.getStringExtra("MyString");

    double amount = Double.parseDouble(myString);

    double res = (amount / 100.0f) * 10;

    String result = String.valueOf(res);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    t.setText(result);


    }
```